# The Fastest way to create a dataframe sample from StackOverflow content

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For pandas related question on StackOverflow , people usually provide their sample data like below:

```
          a         b         c         d         e
0 -0.420430 -0.394562  0.760232  0.152246 -0.671229
1  0.388447  0.676054 -0.058273 -0.246588  0.811332
2 -0.498263 -0.108011  0.952489  0.504729 -0.385724
3  1.069371  0.143752  0.414916 -1.180362 -0.029045
4 -0.245684 -0.150180  0.210579  0.063154  0.261488
5  0.064939 -0.396667  0.857411 -0.460206  0.039658
```

What's the most efficient way to create the data in my own jupyer notebook, so I can further investigate the question?

Usually, I will copy the data about to notepad and replace the space with comma and do the following code to create the sameple data:

```
data = np.array([-0.420430,-0.394562,0.760232,0.152246,...]) # paste the result from notepad here
df = pd.DataFrame(data.reshape(-1,5),columns=[HEADERS_OF_DATA]) # 5 is number of columns
```

However, this is quite slow and inconvenient. Is there any faster way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wonderfully, you can do this with [`pd.read_clipboard()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html).

Just copy the posted DataFrame from the question, and then this line of code will parse it as a DataFrame using `pd.read_table()`:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
```